# Responsive design on android smartphone not fitting to screen

Tags: javascript, android, html, viewport, meta-tags

I'm having problems getting a Viewport which works on an android smartphone.

My site is fully responsive down to 480 pixels wide, whereupon it has a `min-width` set of 480px on the `body` tag.

My first viewport was this:

```
<meta id="myViewport" name="viewport" content="width=screen-width,  user-scalable=yes"/>
```

This worked on most devices I checked, but on an Android phone, it appeared zoomed in and did not automatically shrink-to-fit to the width of the screen.

I then tried using javascript so that `onload`, the width attribute of the viewport changed to `480` rather than `screen-width` should `window.innerWidth < 480`.  This half worked:  when the page loaded, it then resized to fit the screen.  However, during the load, it was still zoomed in, as expected.

Finally, I changed it to...

```
<script>
     if (window.innerWidth < 480) {
          document.write('<meta id="myViewport" name="viewport" content="width=480,  user-scalable=yes"/>');

     }

     else {
          document.write('<meta id="myViewport" name="viewport" content="width=screen-width,  user-scalable=yes"/>');

     }
</script>
```

This goes back to being zoomed-in.  It works on other devices I have used.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1 initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Hope you are missing the scale parameters.

Comment: I need it to be scalable should the user wish it to be, just for it to fit-to-screen when it initially loads.  I have tried with an initial-scale, but that made no difference.

Comment: @RichardB : Hope then it should be the issue with the mediaqueries, try to find out what is the media query getting applied by just putting different bg's.